# jax-ws why does the method call not work?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, soap-client

HI I got the problem that my code is not working but also does not throw an exception or anything else. The program just keeps stuck and nothing is happening. The code sample comes here and can be tested by anyone.

you get the classes with "wsimport -keep -extension http://ars-fiverx.de:8445/WsEchoService.svc?wsdl"

```
URL url = new URL("http://ars-fiverx.de:8445/WsEchoService.svc?wsdl");

    QName qname = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "WsEchoService");

    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

    IWsEchoService iWsEchoService = service.getPort(IWsEchoService.class);
    System.out.println(iWsEchoService.echo());
```

I'm absolutely out of ideas and I don't know what to do... hope that someone can help...

Comment: Are you running in an environment that requires http requests to be sent via a proxy server?

Comment: yes I am, but I also tested it in an environment where I do not use a proxy and it still does not work. So it can't be this